# New Project list not populating v2 (.NET Core)

Tags: visual-studio, .net-core, azure-functions

I have .NET Core 2.2 Installed on system.
While creating new project of type `Azure Function`, there are two options while selecting `Function` type

1. Azure Functions v1 (.Net Framework)
2. Azure Functions v2 Preview (.Net Standard)

Actually wanted to create a new azure function project with .NET Core.
How can we add other types?

I found master list at [this](https://functionscdn.azureedge.net/public/cli-feed-v3.json) location which are the possible types of Azure Functions.

**My System is behind Firewall (Limited Internet access)**

[image]

Comment: Hi Romesh, may I know if your problem was solved ?

Comment: Thanks for your Input, My issue has been resolved by following some steps mentioned in my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My system is behind firewall (Very limited internet access). Due to which while Installing extension `Azure Functions and WebJob Tools` it wasn't installing updated/latest version of Azure Function in `%localappdata%/AzureFunctionsTools/Release/{Version}`. So when I followed steps mentioned [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-tooling-feed/wiki/Fixing-Azure-Function-Core-Tools-download-issues-for-Visual-Studio#execute-an-automated-script), now I am able to see what I am expecting.

Root cause was a domain -> `https://functionscdn.azureedge.net/` which I required to be whitelisted.

Comment: Hi Romesh, I'm glad to hear that your problem was solved. As you provided the solution here, could you please mark your answer as "accepted", this can be beneficial to other community members, thanks~

Answer (score 1):

We can see Azure function v2 uses .NET Core 2.2 from this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-versions)(shown as the screenshot below):
[image]

So as you want to create a new azure function project with .NET Core, you just need to choose azure function v2.